# how to define a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations, between "OneToMany" and "manyToMany polymorphic"?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have three models: "Article", "ArticleTranslation", Tag". 
Article translations in different languages are stored in the ArticleTranslation. 
The "**Article**" model has a **one-to-many** relationship with the "**ArticleTranslation**" model and the "**ArticleTranslation**" model has a **many-to-many polymorphic** relationship with the "**Tag**" model.
 I need to define a convenient shortcut to easily gather all article tags for a given article and I need to define a convenient shortcut to easily gather all the articles that have the given tag.
[image: Relations]

for translate article I use [laravel-translatable](https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable) package.
tables of this relationships:
**articles:**

```
id - integer
```

**article_translations:**

```
id - integer
article_id - integer
locale - string
title - string
slug - string
```

**tags:**

```
id - integer
name - string
slug - string
```

**taggables:**

```
tag_id - integer
taggable_id - integer
taggable_type - string
```

Article Model:

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    use Translatable;
    public $translatedAttributes = ['title', 'slug', 'description', 'body'];
}
```

ArticleTranslation Model:

```php
class ArticleTranslation extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'description', 'body'];

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

Tag Model:

```php
lass Tag extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'name',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function articleTranslate()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(ArticleTranslation::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
first Install this package:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep
This extended version of HasManyThrough allows relationships with unlimited intermediate models.

second, define articleTags() in Article Model:

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
    public function articleTags()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Tag::class,
            [ArticleTranslation::class, 'taggables'],
            [null, ['taggable_type', 'taggable_id'], 'id'],
            [null, null, 'tag_id']
        );
    }
}
```

Third, define articles() in Tag Model:

```php
class Tag extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            ArticleTranslation::class,
            ['taggables', Article::class],
            [null, 'id'],
            [null, ['taggable_type', 'taggable_id']]
        );
    }
}
```